# React Native Import component Error Code 500

Tags: react-native

I have a very simple set up with my React Native project where my App.js files is as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
AppRegistry,
StyleSheet,
Text,
View,
Image
} from 'react-native';
import memberArea from '.android/app/src/components/memberArea';

export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Hello World</Text>
      </View>
  );
 }
}
```

The memberArea.js file is as follows.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  ScrollView.
  AppRegistry
} from 'react-native';



export default class memberArea extends Component<Props> {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchText = ''
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView>
        <TextInput
          placeholder="Search for Restaurants"
          returnKeyType="search"
        />

      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

This is the error message that I receive on my physical device
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0JEJ.jpg)

I have tinkered with many options to no avail. Does anyone have a solution for this or see something that I might be missing? I am running on react-native 0.55.4.

If I remove the import statement in App.js the error goes away and Hello World is printed.

Comment: Can you share your project structure?

Comment: Sorry about that, definitely forgot to include it. But I was able to figure out the issue. While I had already tried the different path given by Sidali Hallak I hadn't realized that the error messages were different. There were two problems here of the incorrect path giving me a hard to read error message. Then, there was another syntax issue where I used '=' rather than ':' to set a state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import memberArea from './android/app/src/components/memberArea';
```

instead of :

```
import memberArea from '.android/app/src/components/memberArea';
```